# beginner question: How can I merge 'function' and 'for phrase'

Tags: python

sorry. I jut start python (It's probably been about two days)

```
def grade(point):
    result = ""
    if point >= 90:
        result = "A"
    elif point >= 80:
        result = "B"
    else:
        result = "C"
    return result

subject_ls = ["English", "Science","math"]
score_ls = [80,90,100]

for data in score_ls:
    result = grade(data)
    for data2 in subject_ls:
        result2 = subject
    print("{} {}".format(result2,result),end="\t")
```

when I run this. 
out is [math B  math A  math A]
I just want [English B, Science A, math A]
What am I missing? plz answer me

Comment: please format the code properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issues is that you are assigning result2 = subject but 'subject' is not defined.

Secondly, the second for loop is running 3 times for each subject which is not what you want.

A simple way to do it is to use while and set a counter and then print the output.

```
i=0
while i< len(subject_ls):
  subject= subject_ls[i]
  result=grade(score_ls[i])
  print("{} {}".format(subject,result),end="\t") 
  i+=1
```

The are shorter ways to do this but since you are new to python you might understand this better!

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, it would be great if you can upvote. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code and use zip for this purpose:

```
for (subject,score) in zip(subject_ls,score_ls):
    print("{} {}".format(subject,grade(score)),end="\t") 

OUT: English B       Science A       math A
```

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't need nesting `for` loops and `subject` is not defined in yours code.

```
def grade(point):
    result = ""
    if point >= 90:
        result = "A"
    elif point >= 80:
        result = "B"
    else:
        result = "C"
    return result
subject_ls = ["English", "Science", "math"]
score_ls = [80, 90, 100]

for i,subject in enumerate(subject_ls):
    print("{} {}".format(subject, score_ls[i]))
```